# Global dynamic path variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several functions in my model

```
#app/model/game.rb    
...

def uncompress_game_files_to_s3 
  UncompressToS3Job.perform_now(self.files, "assets/#{self.id}/game") if self.files
end

def delete_game_files_from_s3 
  DeleteFromS3Job.perform_now("assets/#{self.id}/game")
end

def update_game_index_file_url
  files = FindFilesOnS3Job.perform_now("index.html", "assets/#{self.id}/game")
  self.update_attributes(url: files.first)
end
```

In all these functions, I use `"assets/#{self.id}/game"` for S3 key attribute. I would like to use this expression as global variable `aws_game_path`.

I tried to initialize it in initializer file.

```
#config/initializers/aws.rb
aws_game_path = "assets/#{self.id}/game"
```

but since it is out of the model scope, it raises an error `` undefined method `id' ``. How can I declare such variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ActiveSupport::Concern` Would be best practice in this case.

Follow the below step to make available to all the model

**1:** Create a **`rb`**  lets say `active_record_global_var.rb` extension file in `lib` as **`lib`** file load first.

**2:**  paste the following piece of code.

```
module ActiveRecordExtension

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def set_global_valiable
    set_global_id = self
  end

  module ClassMethods

  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

**3:** Create a file in **`config/initializers/`** directory. Let say `extensions.rb` and put this code snipped into this file.

**4:** `require "active_record_global_var"`

**5:**  Now call `set_global_variable` instances method on model object. This method would be available for **all** model.

**For example:**

`User.last.set_global_valiable.id`  **gives you the id for user**

`CbResume.last.set_global_valiable.id` **same as for CbResume Model**

hope this help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using it from that model, it doesn't need to be global. Can be just a private method:

```
def update_game_index_file_url
  files = FindFilesOnS3Job.perform_now("index.html", game_path)
  self.update_attributes(url: files.first)
end

private

def game_path
  "assets/#{id}/game"
end
```

> How can I declare such varaible.

Variables don't behave this way. It has to be a method on some object. A shared one, if you want to use this logic outside of the model too. Something like this, perhaps:

```
module PathHelpers
  def self.game_path(game)
    "assets/#{game.id}/game"
  end
end

class Game
  def update_game_index_file_url
    files = FindFilesOnS3Job.perform_now("index.html", PathHelpers.game_path(self))
  end
end
```